# What are these air-vent-like structures on this satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite, identify-this-object

I struck out with my [previous question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15300/12102) so I'll try again.

What are these large circular 4-vane structures on the sides of [NOAA-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOAA-19) - the satellite that "fell down"?

They remind me of adjustable air vents but I have a feeling that's not quite right.

You can see them from [another angle here](http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewsr.html?pid=10299).

[image]

**Spacecraft rotated for better view:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: *Spacecraft rotated for better view* :-)

Comment: The [report from NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/65776main_noaa_np_mishap.pdf) on the mishap listed "get-home-itis" as one of the proposed reasons for this thing falling over.

Comment: Those guys in the first photo look pretty casual.

Comment: How thoughtful of them to rotate the spacecraft for you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are thermal control pinwheels.  Reference: figure on page 3 of [this document](http://www.osd.noaa.gov/Spacecraft%20Systems/Pollar_Orbiting_Sat/NOAA_N_Prime/NOAA_NP_Booklet.pdf) .

[image]

Note: odd how the diagram shows 4 devices, but the note says 3.  In the photos there are 3 on one side, and 4 on another.

"[Elements of Space Technology for Aerospace Engineers](https://books.google.com/books?id=gSseFMvSiBoC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=thermal%20control%20pinwheels&source=bl&ots=_isUIwZ85y&sig=RGOnpphVmcgFVTFYp6W6aWY48XY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4t5yqj-HMAhUh64MKHdtuALQQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=thermal%20control%20pinwheels&f=false)", page 302, describes thermal control pinwheels as follows:

> Pinwheel louvers are similar, but in place of rectangular blades
>   incorporate vanes (typically four) in the form of sectors of a circle
>   that together cover one-half of the area under the pinwheel.  They are
>   also rotated by bimetal actuators.  Depending on the position of the
>   sectors, they will cover (uncover) areas that have high ratios of
>   solar absorptivity to emissivity and uncover (cover) areas that have a
>   low such ratio.

And, there is a cross-section:
[image]

Comment: They are some kind of radiator.  I am not sure if the quad blades rotate or not.  Looking for reference.

Comment: These might be the covers, with darker (high emissivity) radiators hidden underneath?

Comment: Possible, and they could rotate to tweak the output.  But haven't found confirmation yet.

Comment: @uhoh Looks like it's what I thought, and they do rotate.  Edited answer.

Comment: Bravo - thank you for that!! Extra credit for a speedy conclusion. I am puzzled, usually absorptivity and emissivity are similar - something back absorbs light and (thermally) radiates light well, something white or metallic is usually poor at both. I'm not sure what's going on here. Maybe the key is *wavelength* - solar radiation (~5000K) is mostly near IR and visible, while "ambient temperature emissivity" (~300K) would be more like 10 to 20 microns. So whatever they use is dark in the visible, but shiny (low $\epsilon$) in IR.

Comment: There may be more info in the linked document, I just skimmed.  Key to the google success was "pinwheel", I never would have come up with that.

Comment: @uhoh, the key is direction, not wavelength: you aim the vents at deep space, which acts as a 3K blackbody, rather than at the Sun, which acts as a 5500K blackbody.

Comment: @Mark The top of the [linked page](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=gSseFMvSiBoC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=thermal+control+pinwheels&source=bl&ots=_isUIwZ85y&sig=RGOnpphVmcgFVTFYp6W6aWY48XY&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=thermal%20control%20pinwheels&f=false) in the book *Elements of Space Technology* by R. X. Meyer it says "*If **this surface** is provided with a high ratio of* **solar radiation absorptivity** *to* **ambient temperature emissivity**, *control over a wide range of temperatures can be obtained*." I think I'm interpreting it correctly - let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I couldn't get the link in your first sentence to work. I found this [https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/111742main_noaa_n_booklet.pdf](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/111742main_noaa_n_booklet.pdf) and is the diagram saying that there are (15) pinwheels?

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, these gizmos are for thermal control. Electronics are mounted inside the structure, under the pinwheels. If the electronics get too hot, then the pinwheel rotates so the high emissivity/low absorptivity surface is uncovered. That surface ten radiates the excess heat and lowers the temperatures. If things then cool off too much, then the pinwheel rotates back the other way - like zipping up your jacket.

Comment: @JohnMcCarthy my answer literally starts with "These are thermal control pinwheels."

Comment: Organic Marble: Sorry if I offended you. I wanted to expand on your answer a bit, and I could have started off without the "just in case". I'll be more careful.