# What are the louver-like structures on the sides of the Mariner 4 probe?

Tags: mars, nasa, identify-this-object, mariner

The COSMOS Magazine article [First mission to Mars: Mariner 4’s special place in history](https://cosmosmagazine.com/space/first-mission-to-mars-mariner-4-s-special-place-in-history) *July 14, 1965, forever changed the way we see Mars. Tim Wallace looks back at one of NASA’s greatest triumphs* recounts some of the excitement that NASA scientists and engineers must have felt during:

> ...humanity’s first up-close encounter with the Red Planet on July 14, 1965, when the pioneering Mariner 4 spacecraft took the first detailed photographs of the Martian surface, paving the way for future missions to successfully land a probe on the ground.

Remember, this is several years *before* the first Moon landing!

The article shows several views of Mariner-4, and this one reminds me of an old slide projector both because of what looks to be the central lens (is that Mariner's camera?) and what looks like louvers or air vents on either side.

**Question:** What are the structures on either side in this image, that look like louvers or air vents? What is their function?

[image: The Mariner 4 spacecraft]

[image: The Mariner 4 spacecraft]

**above x2:** Cropped from image in [COSMOS Magazine](https://cosmosmagazine.com/space/first-mission-to-mars-mariner-4-s-special-place-in-history). "The Mariner 4 spacecraft. CREDIT: NASA / JPL"

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/what-are-these-air-vent-like-structures-on-this-satellite

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm not so sure that these structures on the side of Mariner-4's are actually louvers or vents. But thanks for the link, I remember that one now :-)

Comment: Aren't they temperature control devices on both spacecraft? Just one spins and the other louvers open, to control the amount of heat rejected?

Comment: @OrganicMarble r.e Mariner 4 I just don't know either way yet. The large and yet flat apertures shown in your link expose the surface to almost 2π of space, whereas louvers are restrictive and have a preferred, more narrow direction of exposure to space, so they would be less effective. I want to wait until I can read further.

Comment: Look at the textbook linked in my answer to your old question, it describes "venetian blind" louvers on the same page as pinwheels.

Comment: @OrganicMarble okay, indeed louvers are "a thing".

Comment: They are quite common. Used to see them on shuttle payloads all the time. And now cubesats https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2016/nasa-repurposes-passive-thermal-control-technology-for-cubesats/

Comment: @OrganicMarble So far the only thing I have to go on (re Mariner 4) is one hard-to-read bit of writing on the first image in the only answer (so far). I you would be interested in adding a supporting answer with a bit more about louvers (and a Shuttle-era example for comparison and/or that cool 10x10cm item in your new link) that would be great!

Comment: Lets see if we can get @prakhar to up their game with some better links etc. Their answer is right just not well supported.

Comment: Here's a rather famous Shuttle payload with thermal louvers, between the arm attachment point and the white rectangular instrument. https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-109/hires/sts109-708-054.jpg

Comment: And here's a SPARTAN free-flying release and catch satellite from Shuttle - it's louver-tacular! https://airandspace.si.edu/webimages/collections/full/A20040121000cp22.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some googling, you were indeed right it is Temperature control louvers.

[image: Louver labelled]

More detailed labelling for mariner 5 is in this image
[image: Not Mariner 4]

These louvers  control temperature inside the spacecraft. It is a passive temperature control system. [Spacecraft Thermal Control](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_thermal_control)

Accordingly, it seems that circular thing is a thruster
[image: Mariner 4]

Detailed labelling
[image: Mariner 4]

Image credits : NASA/JPL-Caltech

Image source :  m.caltech.edu

Comment: Added, it seems it is a thruster

Comment: Added image source and credits. The credit obviously belongs to NASA/JPL. Thanks for guiding.

Comment: If you look at almost all other answers in this SE site which have images, you will see that people add *links directly to the sources of each image*.

Comment: @Prakhar it's actually considered passive thermal control despite the moving parts. No cooling loop. https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2016/nasa-repurposes-passive-thermal-control-technology-for-cubesats/

Comment: Also of interest: https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/louvers-temperature-control-system-mariner-2

Comment: @organic Yes, it indeed looked like passive to me. I was misguided by the article saying " Active Thermal control components include louvers ". I misinterpreted as the system though it was talking about components.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran across the louvers in close-up view!

In the JLP video [1965: Discovery at Mars](https://youtu.be/q5dzDWjN7Z4) there is an excellent video *The Changing Face of Mars* with introductory remarks by its producer/director/writer, Blaine Baggett, Director, Office of Communication and Education, JPL, about Mariner 3 and 4 missions to Mars embedded within his Von Karman lecture.

At about `00:38:50` you can see them "moving" (could be Mariner 3 or 4):

[image: Mariner 4 thermal louvers]

Answer (score 1):

They are, in fact, called louvers, and they are for thermal control. Under the louver is a radiator designed to reject waste heat efficiently. When the louver is open, the radiator has a good view of cold space and dumps heat. But close the louver, and the heat rejection drops substantially. Louvers are used when the spacecraft has heat sources which vary dramatically with time. I worked on the Dawn spacecraft, launched in 2007, and we used louvers. In Dawn's case, the ion propulsion system used gobs of power and, since it wasn't 100% efficient, it also generate lots of waste heat. When it was running, the louvers were wide open to reject that heat and prevent it from overheating the rest of the spacecraft. Turn off the ion propulsion system, and the lovers closed - kind of like zipping up your winter coat. The diagram below shows the location of the louvers on Dawn.

http://104.131.251.97/spacecraft/wp-content/uploads/sites/18/2015/08/9348258_orig.jpg

Louvers are passive devices which require no commands or motors to open and close. They use a bimetallic strip like a thermostat to turn temperature changes into (small) forces which, in zero g, are enough to open and close the louvers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_thermal_control#Louvers

http://matthewwturner.com/uah/IPT2008_summer/baselines/LOW%20Files/Thermal/Spacecraft%20Thermal%20Control%20Handbook/09.pdf

Comment: Thanks! there's a new question that may or may not have louvers as an answer: [First use of spacecraft thermal control louvers, doors, pinwheels, or other things that physically actuate either passively or actively?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58030/12102)